# Generalized assignment problem with worker creation costs

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have a generalized assignment problem, where each worker can have many tasks, and where there's a (non-integer) cost for *starting* a worker. I want to minimize costs. The starting cost can be pretty high, so it's preferable not to start a worker, if possible.

Is this solvable, or can it be at least approximated? I'm totally new to LP/MIP and am having trouble finding papers / lectures / textbooks.

e.g. if there're two workers A,B and two tasks 1,2 with costs

```
A1=1.4, B1=6, A2=3, B2=24
```

Then normally, the optimal configuration is `A2,B1` (Task 2 on A, Task 1 on B), the total cost being `9`.

But in my situation the initial cost of creating each worker is say, `90`. So the optimal configuration becomes `A1,B1`.

Moreover, workers are bound by the total volume of the tasks (e.g. RAM pre-configured by each worker) they can be assigned.

Comment: I think there are a couple of typos. First of all, in the normal configuration, why wouldn't I pick $A1$ instead of $B1$, since $1.4<6$? I'm guessing you meant $A1=14$. With costs added in, I would expect $A_1,A_2$, not $A_1,B_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, with any reasonable LP/MIP solver, you're going to have no problem here. The model looks like this so far:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & 14 A_1 + 6 B_1 + 3 A_2 + 24 B_2 \\
\text{subject to} & A_1 + B_1 = 1 \\ & A_2 + B_2 = 1 \\ &A_0, A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2 \in\{0,1\}
\end{array}
Now let's add two new variables $A_0$ and $B_0$
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & 90 A_0 + 90 B_0 + 14 A_1 + 6 B_1 + 3 A_2 + 24 B_2 \\
\text{subject to} & A_1 + B_1 = 1 \\ & A_2 + B_2 = 1 \\ 
& 2 A_0 >= A_1 + A_2 \\ & 2 B_0 >= B_1 + B_2 \\
& A_0, A_1, A_2, B_0, B_1, B_2 \in\{0,1\}
\end{array}
The constraint $2 A_0 >= A_1 + A_2$ ensures that $A_0$ is nonzero if either one of the tasks is assigned to $A$; similarly for $B$.

Any other linear equations and inequalities involving the task assignments can easily be added.